# CTE To Return All Related Ids Regardless of Separation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will select all related rows from a relationship table, regardless of how distant the relationship.  I know I can query a parent/child hierarchy recursively using a CTE, but this doesn't really fit the parent/child mold, it's more like an x degrees of separation.

```
Create Table #Relationships (
    Relationship_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Person_Id_1 int NOT NULL,
    Person_Id_2 int NOT NULL
)

Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (1, 2)
Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (1, 3)
Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (4, 3)
Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (4, 5)
Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (6, 1)
Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (7, 8)
Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (7, 9)
Insert Into #Relationships (Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2) Values (9, 10)

Select Relationship_Id, Person_Id_1, Person_Id_2 From #Relationships
/*
Relationship_Id Person_Id_1 Person_Id_2
--------------- ----------- -----------
1               1           2
2               1           3
3               4           3
4               4           5
5               6           1
6               7           8
7               7           9
8               9           10
*/
```

Given the above table, I want a query that when passed an Id will return all other Ids that are in some way related to it, regardless of how many degrees of separation.  For example, passing the following Ids would give me the results below.

```
5 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
1 = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
8 = 7, 9, 10
```

Is this even possible?  I can't wrap my head around what the base case would be to stop the recursion.

Comment: Its not obvious to me how your relationships actually work for example how is 5 related to 6?

Comment: 1 is related to 6 directly.  Anyone related to 1 is also related to 6.  1 is related to 3, which is related to 4, which is related to 5, hence 5 is related to 6.